# org.postgis.PGgeometry cannot be cast to org.postgis.PGgeometry

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wildfly, postgis

I am migrating the connection mode of a project 
from:
using `DriverManager` 
to 
`DataDource`.
But I got this error:

```
org.postgis.PGgeometry cannot be cast to org.postgis.PGgeometry
```

I try to put in and take out the Libray Postgis form the server and the Project but without results

Thank in advance for the help

Comment: Mor info:from:

1)using DriverManager (Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\src.zip!\java\sql\DriverManager.java)
properties.put("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
Class.forName("net.bull.javamelody.JdbcDriver");
conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties);

to 

2) DataDource (Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\src.zip!\javax\sql\DataSource.java)
 Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
 DataSource datasource = (DataSource)initialContext.lookup("java:jboss/datasources/postgresql/Tsubasa");
 this.conexion = datasource.getConnection();

Comment: Please all possible details in the question above and hightlight the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly caused by having 2 jar/library files on the classpath with this class in it.

Check your classpath locations for Wildfly and make sure you only have *one* copy of the postgis library on the classpath.

If you don't find the duplicate, check some more - you will find it eventually.

One way to do this is use the following code to locate the class (it will print the jar file the class is loaded from):

```
Class klass = String.class;
URL location = klass.getResource('/' + klass.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class");
```

Then, remove that jar from your classpath and run the same code to get the next location until you locate/remove them all.

Then, add *one* back.

Set the maven scope to `provided` and it will compile but not package it if you are using a library packaged in Wildfly, just make sure you have the same version.

`provided` means your project needs it to compile/test/run but that it will be provided by the container you are running in (Wildfly, in your case).

See here for details: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Comment: Thank you very much mikedb! Is true, the library is in two places: 1-pakaged in the project by maven 2-in the server wildfly If i take out from the 1 the project doesn´t compile If i take out from 2 at run time came out with the error: ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) java.lang.ClassCastException: org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to org.postgis.PGgeometry

It seems that can´t use the library pakaged (1) at certain point and need the one in the server (2)

Comment: See my edits - use `provided` scope in maven, it's made for this case. Make sure the versions are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much mikedb!
Is true, the library is in two places:
1-pakaged in the project by maven 
2-in the server wildfly
If i take out from the 1 the project doesn´t compile
If i take out from 2 at run time came out with the error:
ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) java.lang.ClassCastException: org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to org.postgis.PGgeometry

It seems that can´t use the library pakaged (1) at certain point and need the one in the server (2)

Answer (score 0):

We solve this problem adding the jar as a module:

$ ls -1 postgres/
postgis-jdbc-2.2.1.jar
postgresql-42.2.12.jar

$ wildfly-20.0.0.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect

[standalone@localhost:9990 /] module add --name=org.postgresql --resources=postgres/postgresql-42.2.12.jar,postgres/postgis-jdbc-2.2.1.jar --resource-delimiter=, --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=postgresql:add(driver-name=postgresql, driver-module-name=org.postgresql, driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver)
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] data-source add --jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/postgresql/NameDS --name=NameDS --connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://10.1.1.94:5432/NameBD --driver-name=postgresql --user-name=geomatica --password=***